# navigation arrows in linux terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, c++

I have current LTS ubuntu and yet again I noticed something wrong. Right now in default install CTRL+[left/right] doesn't jump by word. Kind of strange, if I'm not mistaken, I think I had it working in properly in default freebsd like 10 years ago. Anyways, it seems that even default left and right do not work properly by default! If I type:

```
pxd[LEFT][LEFT][DEL]w[ENTER]
```

then I get `pwd`, obviously (hopefully?)
What I noticed now is that it doesn't work that way in a plain c++ cmd line app. Here's sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        cout << "\n\n{\n" << s << "\n}" << endl;
}
```

now compile and run it: `g++ test.cpp -o test && ./test` and enter that same key sequence that resulted in `pwd` in bash. Suddenly it won't work. I get this mess: `p[3~w`

What is wrong with terminal in all *nixes?

Comment: The cute cartoon helped me wade through the rant, but it seems like what your asking boils down to a C++ question, because it's basically asking why C++ code behaves that way.  What do you get if you replicate this in Windows?

Comment: @fixer1234 off course it works on windows properly. It's not C++ specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple functions such as the `getline()` method use the kernel's tty driver's cooked mode which only has some really basic line editing capabilities (backspace, `^W` to delete a word etc.), but no support for arrows or such.

To get full line editing capabilities, you should use the `readline` library instead of `getline()`.

Comment: that's ghetto. I don't know how possibly I'd missed that it had that issue on unix